# Java - How to define a parameterized constructor?

Tags: constructor

Java - Define a parameterized constructor for the Circle class that when passed one integer parameter, copies it into the radius instance variable.

```
    Test                                    Input                               Result
    Circle r = new Circle (10);             Parameter is 10                     10
    System.out.println(r.radius);           Parameter is 3456                   3456



  Class Circle {

  public int radius;
  //PLEASE HELP ME HERE
```

}

Very basic question I guess, I'm new to programming. Thank you so much for helping me!

Comment: Please share more details. What do you mean by "parameterized constructor"? Which programming language do you use?

Comment: Assuming that you are asking about Java, this will be explained in any Java text book or online Java tutorial site you care to look at.   For example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html  Please do some research before asking questions.